# How many combinations can you make with 3 digits?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-property

So my mom- a teacher - called me and my brother and gave us each a paper and pencil.

She said: Think of three *distinct* single digit positive integers (0 to 9) and write down as many numbers (number combinations) you can make with those three without adding any math operations (like ^ for example).*No repeating same digits in your  numbers*. So I want to see only single, double and triple digit numbers.Remember just numbers, no math operations.

We got busy. My brother got 26 different numbers. I got more! I was creative.

What did we both get?

> Note: If you choose say a,b and c you cannot write aa or aab etc

Comment: This sounds like it should just be a polynomial but then it hits you with the 26. Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

At my first stab at this, I can get to <s>48</s> **78**. I avoided using superscript, assuming that that would violate your math rule.

We choose the digits:

> 5, 6, 7

Which can net us the following numbers:

> 756, 576, 765, 567, 675, 657

> Flip the 6 around to get
>  759, 579, 795, 597, 975, 957

> Tilt the 7 ever-so-slightly to get
>  156, 516, 165, 561, 615, 651

> Flip the 6 and tilt the 7 to get
>  159, 519, 195, 591, 915, 951

> Write the 5 very strongly on the back of the paper to show through and get
>  726, 276, 762, 267, 672, 627

> Then the nonsense with the other two digits again:
>  129, 219, 192, 291, 912, 921
>  729, 279, 792, 297, 972, 927
>  126, 216, 162, 261, 612, 621

Then let's throw in the 1 and 2 digit numbers to the count (thanks @WeatherVane) for a bonus 30:

> 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9
>  12, 15, 16, 19
>  21, 26, 27, 29
>  51, 56, 57, 59
>  61, 62, 65, 67
>  72, 75, 76, 79
>  91, 92, 95, 97

Let's try to find 26 numbers. The regular permutations of non-zero digits gives 15 distinct numbers, which is 11 too few:

> 5, 6, 7, 56, 57, 67, 65, 75, 76, 567, 576, 657, 675, 756, 765

But then if we

> arbitrarily choose the "flip the 6" from before, we get:
>  9, 59, 79, 95, 97, 597, 579, 759, 795, 957, 975

which gets us up to 26. Let's say that's where the overlap is, and that the OP found more by using one or more of the above tricks that I listed.

Comment: Not to mention 1 and 2 digit numbers, which the description allows.

Comment: rot13(Ner qrpvzny cbvagf nyybjrq, be qb gubfr nyfb pbhag nf "zngu bcrengvbaf")?

Comment: Another option might be to rot13(jevgr lbhe qvtvgf yvxr n frira frtzrag qvfcynl naq pbzovar n fvk naq avar gb trg na rvtug)

Comment: "What did we **both** get?" What 26 numbers did the **brother** get? Without any fudging, I can get 15 numbers (the regular perms excluding $0$ digit because $012$ and $12$ are not "different numbers").

Comment: You can convert an 8 to a double zero.

Comment: @FlorianF For what purpose? One of the rules of the problem is "No repeating same digits in your numbers".

Comment: Good point!  OK, so no.